# React component default props with graphql

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

I'm trying to fetch records from backend graphql service and render them with Array.map function. Unfortunately before they're loaded I get error because they are undefined. I tried to set default props on component but it didin't work. Do i have to check if everything is loaded or is there specific way to inject default values into those props. My code looks like that right now

```
import React from 'react';
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';
import { fetchTasks } from '../../../graphql/tasks';
import { Dashboard } from '../components/Dashboard';

const propTypes = {
    data: React.PropTypes.shape({
        tasks: React.PropTypes.array
    })
};

const defaultProps = {
    data: {
        tasks: []
    }
};

class DashboardContainer extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const titles = this.props.data.tasks.map(task => task.title);
        return(
            <Dashboard
                titles={titles}
            />
        );
    }
}

DashboardContainer.propTypes = propTypes;
DashboardContainer.defaultProps = defaultProps;

export default graphql(fetchTasks)(DashboardContainer);
```

Comment: Yes you have to check if your prop is updated with value you required. So you need to check this.props.data.tasks.length and if it exists then you map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you have to check if the query has finished to load. You could go through this nice [tutorial](https://www.learnapollo.com/tutorial-react/react-02#Displaying[object%20Object]information[object%20Object]of[object%20Object]your[object%20Object]trainer), where you build a pokemon app. The link points to the part where they show a basic query and how you check if it is loaded.

In your case it could look like this:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';
import { fetchTasks } from '../../../graphql/tasks';
import { Dashboard } from '../components/Dashboard';

const propTypes = {
  data: React.PropTypes.shape({
    tasks: React.PropTypes.array
  })
};

const defaultProps = {
  data: {
    tasks: []
  }
};

class DashboardContainer extends React.Component {
  render() {
    if (this.props.data.loading) {
      return <div > Loading < /div>;
    }

    const titles = this.props.data.tasks.map(task => task.title);
    return ( <
      Dashboard titles = {
        titles
      }
      />
    );
  }
}

DashboardContainer.propTypes = propTypes;
DashboardContainer.defaultProps = defaultProps;

export default graphql(fetchTasks)(DashboardContainer);
```